# Scalability and performance in Meteor

Tags: android, iphone, performance, meteor

I've really enjoyed experimenting with Meteor recently and so far i've found it to be a really neat little app. I've decided to migrate an old application over to meteor and have already made some good progress. The application is a live score updates application. While i've been able to demonstrate the concept i've found 2 issues which may prevent me from using it.

1) Data previously existed in a mySQL database so i've written a script to export the data into .js files. For those that might want to do similar, the main part of the PHP code is here.

```
$handle = fopen($output_file, "w");

foreach ( $tables as $key => $table ) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_prefix$table";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {

                $newTableName = "";

                $parts = explode("_", $table);
                foreach ( $parts as $k => $v ) {
                        $newTableName .= ucfirst($v);
                }

                $string = $newTableName.".insert({";
                $first = true;
                foreach ( $row as $columnName =>  $value ) {
                        if ( !$first ) { $string .= ", "; }
                        $string .= "$columnName : \"$value\"";
                        $first = false;
                }
                $string .= " });";
                print $string . "<br>";

        }
}
```

While this has worked for most of the tables, i have one table in particular which contains all the event information. This separate .js file contains 3600 lines of insert statements and it would seem that when this is in the application, the application breaks. If i rename the file to be 'event.js.save' for example, then the application is fine. More specifically, with this .js file in place, when i deploy the application i get..

```
mac:app user$ meteor deploy <domain>.meteor.com
Deploying to <domain>.meteor.com.  Bundling ...

Errors prevented deploying:
Exception while bundling application:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

So, Question number 1 is - how much has been done to test the scalability of this appliction?

2) The second issue i have is regarding mobile performance. I've spent a long time getting a stylesheet looking good on all platforms and have been really disappointed to see how quickly the battery on a mobile goes down.

When i load a page in Safari the 'progress' animation in the top right is constantly spinning and from what i've seen 5% of battery goes in probably 10 minutes.

Question number 2 - how is the connection kept alive for browsers? Is there anything that can be done to reduce the impact on mobile browsers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:
Applications are very scalable in the case that the meteor site managed the launch just fine with a massive amount of traffic all in one day when they had not planned for it.
The reason for your error is that you can't call that many statements that are the same in a row as far as I'm aware as js thinks it is crashing. I think there are ways to change this however or get round it.

As far as testing they have done I'm unsure, personally I would import the data by itterating through the data and inserting it rather than having it as that many calls (I think that is the issue).

2:
That is a bug that it is spinning however it is constantly checking over ajax or similar methods.
In future sockets will be used which I expect will be more efficient.
Perhaps there will be a way to tune down the number of queries and network intensive it is in the future.

Comment: The spinning actually works as designed, as far as the browser is concerned. It's triggered by the AJAX: AJAX means something's loading, if something's loading the wheel spins : )

Comment: Cheers for the backup below :), yeah not certain I want a spinning wheel when AJAX is loading personally.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've been able to resolve the situation now by changing my code slightly as you suggested. I've posted a reply below with the updated code and comments on #2. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the performance and network issues, have you thought about using a pub/sub protocol such as MQTT ( http://mqtt.org/faq ) to post the updates? These would mean that you wouldn't need to poll for updates and would have them pushed to the clients instead.

Comment: afeltham - I'm guessing you don't directly mean use that but just a mail queue style event push right?
Meteor will be using web sockets eventually which will enable that type of technology :).

I say the spinning icon was a bug as that is why they have not enabled web sockets as it caused among other issues a spinning icon all the time.

Comment: Yeah i appreciate that the spinning icon thing is out of your control although it does seem to signify that *something* is happening and from what i've seen that really affects battery life. I've only recently started looking at the source but at the moment i don't see why you couldn't use something like MQTT to handle the messaging between clients. I might have missed something obvious though.... ?

Comment: Well Afeltham it will be solved but the limiting factors are web transports and browsers. MQTT seems to use ports that are not supported on the web and streams content back and forth. This is basically how web sockets work on the web which then you can build the other technology in MQTT upon. The limiting factor is web socket support in browsers, which meteor handles will handle with backwards compatibility AJAX and other methods. Look up sockjs which is Meteors current transport framework it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an updated source code to the issue above :

As discussed in one of the answers, the problem seemed to be the number of insert lines and that it was Javascript breaking not Meteor. I've since updated the code and thought others might be interested to.

The following PHP provides JSON output for a table...

```
// we connect to example.com and port 3307
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db = mysql_select_db("databasename");
$tables = array (
        $_REQUEST["table"]
        );
$table_prefix = "tableprefix_";
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
foreach ( $tables as $key => $table ) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_prefix$table";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        $first = true;
        print "[";
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
                if ( !$first ) { print ", "; }
                $first = false;
                print ( json_encode($row) . "\n");
        }
        print "]";
}
mysql_close($link);
```

I can then use the following in the javascript to load the data.

```
Events = new Meteor.Collection("event");

if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Events.find().count() === 0) {
        $.getJSON('/ajax/event.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        Events.insert(val);
                });
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I would strongly advised you create a fixture file in server side and run a startup migration if your collection doesn't exist, and consider add index on your data, rather than doing it via ajax. It speeds up things considerably.

Answer (score -7):

jonathanKingston said,

> 1: Applications are very scalable in the case that the meteor site
>   managed the launch just fine with a massive amount of traffic all in
>   one day when they had not planned for it.

Which is hilarious, because the home page for Meteor is not a Meteor app, and they had to take all Meteor demo apps off-line due to security / scalability reasons.

Looking forward to the next generation of FUD being spread by stupid programmers conned by pretty demos and Hacker News posts.

Comment: If you had taken the time to look at the Meteor.com source code you'd see it's running on meteor..

Comment: I think at time of launch, Meteor was and you will notice now Meteor.com isn't using the at least the dev branch version of meteor as it is rendering the HTML.

Meteor isn't insecure and the docs app is still an app as it always has been :).